# Audio player repeat button behavior

Tags: audio

I'm creating an audio player for Android and I would like it to have repeat function (apart from simple play/pause functions). However I'm not sure how should the repeat button behave.

I see two options here:

**A)** It only rewinds the audio to the beginning without changing the playback state. If the audio is paused, it remains paused.

**B)** It rewinds the audio and it also starts the playback. So if the audio is paused, it is started automatically.

Which option would you recommend?

Comment: To clarify, the "repeat" feature you are thinking about is a way to restart the audio rather than repeating the same audio within a list when one audio is over?

Comment: My player is used for single track so it should "restart" the same track.

Comment: Repeat is not the same as restart.  Why does it 'restart'?

Comment: Maybe I didn't use the right word. The button should rewind the track to the beginning and thus allow the user to play the track again once it finished. It seems that option B should be more suitable for this as users probably wouldn't use this button when audio is paused. Or would they?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your "repeat" is being used on single audio track that restarts the audio form the beginning.

Looks like the question is whether a "repeated" track should auto-play even if it's paused.

My opinion is that most people want to restart the track because they want to hear it over again from the beginning. So even if it's paused, I assume that he/she wants to start listening. In addition, if you do go with **option A**, it'll require two clicks for people who want to repeat and start listening (can be frustrating).

**Option B** looks like the better choice for me.

Comment: Ok, thank you. And what about when we add new button with function "rewind 10 seconds back". Do you think this is the same situation?

Comment: I think it'll be the same case with rewind 10 seconds but this is something you should user test. On a different note I'm not sure what's the significants of rewind 10 seconds but if you're looking for a more flexible UI, a slider may be more common that allows users to drag and rewind as far back as they want. Again, I don't have knowledge of what you're designing so it may not apply.

Comment: I'm using slider to rewind the track as well. 10 second rewind is customer's request.